# Python blending concatenated Images

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, blending

I am using Python and PIL to concatenate two images and trying to remove the attached boundary or seam to get a smoother and natural image without any artifacts.

```
def merge_images(image1, image2, mask):

    img1 = Image.open(image1)
    img2 = Image.open(image2)
    mask = Image.open(mask).convert('RGBA')

    #mask.show()

    height = img1.size[1] + (img2.size[1])
    width = img1.size[0]

    print(height , width)

    #height = img1.size[1]
    #width = img1.size[0]+(img2.size[0]/2)

    print(height - img1.size[1])

    newImage = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), (0,0,0))
    newImage.paste(img1, (0 , (height - img1.size[1])))
    #newImage.show()
    print(newImage.size)
    #newImage.paste(img1, ((width-img1.size[0]),0))
    newImage.paste(img2, (0 ,0), mask)

    return newImage
```

This is referred from [Blend Images](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/u18ds/image_stitching_in_python_with_images_that_have/)

This is the expected output from the above link: [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEgi6.jpg)

I am not getting the same results and there is considerable seam in the concatenated image result.

Source:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Result]

The result is far off from the original. I am looking to remove the seam in the attached region and possibly the shadow at the bottom of the top image. I am guessing the problem is in the masking. Any suggestions would be very useful

Edit: Missed adding the mask image
[Mask Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjWzT.jpg)

Comment: what is your question

Comment: I am getting the improperly formatted code error if I add more links and descriptions. Trying to figure it out

Comment: In the code you show, function `merge_images` has no body, and there's a return statement outside a function. Maybe you should fix your indentation, it kinda matters in Python.

Comment: I am not getting a syntax error, It happens when I paste it and if I try to format it, I am stuck with the same error. Been an hour at this now!!

Comment: Paste code, select code, hit Ctrl+K (or the button with `{ }` on it).

Comment: @DanMašek: Thank you for editing, I am not sure why it was happening today when I have posted similar questions with code. Guess one of those bad days!

Comment: In the reddit post you refer to, they have the images overlap and use a mask that contains a gradient to achieve the blended transition. You don't have any overlap, so that approach can't work.

Comment: You need to align your `images` so you can do multiply operations. So in best case your `sourceA`, `sourceB` and `mask` image should be the same shape

Comment: @DanMašek: I have included the gradient mask image used. By Images overlap, you mean similar features? As far as I can see, the images there are totally different from one another. In fact, the images I am using have more similarity.

Comment: @user1767754: Multiply Operations? My images are all of same dimensions (1920 X 1080) Can you clarify more?

Comment: @WilbusFugu No, I don't mean features. Imagine those pictures are two sheets of paper. You have them edge by edge, they have a scenario where part of one lies on top of the other. The overlapping area is what you blend to make that gradual transition.

Comment: @DanMašek: So in my case, I should overlay and then blend? Any example would help me immensely.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example I've created that demonstrates how you could blend two images using an alpha mask. Most import note,  `width` and `height` should be all same for all inputs. Images are attached to the source so it can be reproduced correctly.

The core idea is, that you multiply the pixels of `lion` image with the alpha, and use the `rest` to multiply it with the `taj` image. This is called `weighted blending`

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

lion = cv2.imread('lion.png',3)
taj = cv2.imread('taj.png',3)
alpha = cv2.imread('mask.png',0).astype(np.float32)


a_B, a_G, a_R = cv2.split(lion)
b_B, b_G, b_R = cv2.split(taj)

b = (a_B * (alpha/255.0)) + (b_B * (1.0 - (alpha/255.0)))
g = (a_G * (alpha/255.0)) + (b_G * (1.0 - (alpha/255.0)))
r = (a_R * (alpha/255.0)) + (b_R * (1.0 - (alpha/255.0)))
output = cv2.merge((b,g,r))


cv2.imwrite("lionoutput.png", output)
```

> **Taj**

[image]

> **lion**

[image]

> **mask**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear and detailed example. The result I am trying to achieve is similar to the reddit link given in my post above. My problem is to Stitch Images if there are matching features else stack or concatenate them seamlessly. In the reddit link, after merging, the target image is twice the size of the originals and there is no clear seam present, that is the result I am trying (i.e.) Stack two images vertically without any seam that shows the region or boundary

Comment: Btw, this is not the answer to my post, as my condition is different from the one given as an answer, however thanks for the detail

Comment: I think the idea from here on should be pretty straight forward? No Luck so far?

Comment: @user1767754 how can I make a mask like this going in different directions or at different rates of change?

Comment: @mLstudent33 I've created it with photoshop, but you could use a gradient generator like https://angrytools.com/gradient/image/